# UITableView with indexing in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, indexing

I have an app that uses the Navigation Controller with a TableView inside. It takes data from the array and displays them on the screen. I'd like them to be indexed like on the photo here:

[image]

So I would like to have custom indexes different for different groups of elements.

For example: the first 10 cells would have a string "One", the second 10 cells would have "Two" and so on. Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use table with section header.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as CustomHeaderCell
headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor()

switch (section) {
case 0:
  headerCell.headerLabel.text = "One";

case 1:
  headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Two";

case 2:
  headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Three";

default:
  headerCell.headerLabel.text = "Next";
}

return headerCell
}
```